# How do I get maven to look for the war file instead of the jar file?

Tags: maven

Maven tries to look for the jar file instead of the war file when I add this dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-examples</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The jar file doesn't seem to be in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 but the war file exists. How do I get maven to look for the war file instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
   <artifactId>wicket-examples</artifactId>
   <version>6.6.0</version>
   <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```